# В терминале ubuntu в windows 10 не видно файлов в дирректории

Tags: linux, bash, windows-10

> Подскажите в чем может быть проблема в терминале Ubuntu в Windows 10
>   не видит файлы которые я скопировал в папку, если создавать через
>   терминал то всё создается и всё видно...

после перезагрузки созданные файлы видит, походу это баг...

[image: скриншот]

Comment: Откуда у вас папка c:\LocalState\rootfs?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: вот полный путь c:\Users\neon\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs\home\neon\.ssh\

Comment: @NeOn, добавьте эту информацию вопрос — под вопросом есть кнопка-ссылка «править».

Comment: А вы случаем не пробовали копировать руками в эту папку из-под windows?